# How insert values into a row using a hashmap in mybatis while using annotations?

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I can insert into db using MyBatis if I have an object like,

```
public class Student {
   private int id;
   private String name;
}
..
@Insert("INSERT INTO STUDENT (ID,NAME) VALUES (#{id}, #{name})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
void insert(Student student);
```

But how can I use mybatis if I have a hashmap with values as,

```
studentDetailsMap = [{id,10},{name,"smith"}] //represented as key value pairs for understanding
```

What I have are big tables with so much columns and the data is available to mybatis as a hashmap for each row. There are so many such cases, so I dont want to create a lot pojo classes that is why I am trying to find a way to insert directly from hashmap to mybatis.

Comment: It's pretty much the same with a HashMap. If it didn't work, you should explain what you tried and how it didn't work exactly.

Comment: @ave You were right. It is pretty much the same way. The hashmap i had was missing some values which the row required, hence it was causing errors.

Comment: Glad to know the problem was resolved. :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the mapper element in the mapper XML:

   `<insert id="fnInsert">
       insert into ${tablename}
       <trim>
           <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
               <foreach collection="mapdata" item="element" index="index"
                   separator=",">${index}</foreach>

           </trim>  select <foreach collection="mapdata" item="element" index="index"
               separator=",">
               <trim>
                   #{element}
               </trim>
           </foreach>  from dual
               </trim>
   </insert>`

---

2. Create corresponding function in the interface.

`public int insertMICTables(@Param("tablename") String tablename, @Param("mapdata") Map<String, String> mapdata);`

3. Prepare input parameters:

   ```
   Map<String, String> mapdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
   mapdata.put("columna", "id01");
   mapdata.put("columnb", "Hello manager");
   this._epMapper.insertMICTables("tablename", mapdata) ;
   ```